# Summing the 1s from a list in python

Tags: python, list

Given I have the task that I have to count the number of 1s entailed in a list. Upon assessing the prior my code is giving the message "NONE."

What am I doing wrong ?

```
#alternative: 
result=[]

def count(x):
    for i in enumerate(x):
        if i==1:
            sum(i)
            append.result(i)
            return result 

c = count([1, 4, 5, 1, 3])
print(c)
```

Comment: You are doing *a lot* wrong. `enumerate` produces an index and value you are treating it as a single value. You are calling `sum()` for some reason and not assigning the result to a variable. You are returning inside the loop (and the `if`). You probably want to return the sum at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want it like this:

```
result=[]

def count(x):
    for i in x:
        if i==1:
            result.append(i)
    return len(result) 

c = count([1, 4, 5, 1, 3])
print(c)
```

Output

```
2'
```

Or you could simplify it further by:

```
def count(x):
    result = 0
    for j, i in enumerate(x):
        if i==1:
            result +=1
    return result
```

Or, if you want to use `pandas`, you can write it even more simple:

```
import pandas as pd

def count(x):
    x = pd.Series(x)
    return x.value_counts().loc[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mark mentioned, using enumerate here isn't very helpful, as it creates an index and a value, when in this case, you only care about the value. Since x is already a list, you don't need to use enumerate.

Be careful to wait until after your loop is done to use `return` in this case, as you're exiting the loop when the first 1 is encountered.

Additionally, be sure that you're actually assigning the value to something, rather than just outputting it. Doing `sum(i)` doesn't really do anything in this case, especially because you already checked that `i==1`!

Also, the syntax for adding to a list is `x.append(value)` where x is the list. There are easier ways to do this, such as with a list comprehension:

```
def count(x):
    return len([value for value in x if value==1])
```

Or expanded out:

```
def count(x):
    result = []
    for value in x:
        if value == 1:
            result.append(value)
    return len(result)
```

Or generalized for any number n:

```
def count(x, n):
    result = []
    for value in x:
        if value == n:
            result.append(value)
    return len(result)
```

And the generalized form as a list comprehension:

```
def count(x, n):
    return len([value for value in x if value==n])
```

Additionally, you could use python's built in count function, but I suspect that if this is an assignment of some sort, that may be disallowed, but that can be used like so:

```
x = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 5]
num_1s = x.count(1)
print(str(num_1s))
```

Which outputs `3`

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1, 4, 5, 1, 3]
l.count(1)
```

Will output `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(x):
    result = []
    for i,num in enumerate(x):
        if num==1:
            result.append(num)
    return len(result)
c = count([1, 4, 5, 1, 3])
print('There %d ones in the list'%c)
```

I don't think you are using enumerate properly, also sum(i) is not being stored in memory so it does not do anything. Finally, make sure you append onto your list correctly.

Comment: I should have indented the code following the definition of the function, but I hope the rest makes sense.

Comment: This makes no sense. You are not using the value `x` and you are returning inside the loop. Your function returns `[1]` regardless of what you pass in.

Comment: I tried improving the answer but I realized that I would end up making it a right answer to the question, then I thought it is a good practice you figure it yourself with the indentation and also think about what @Mark said to see if you can fix it up. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 three main issues here.

Firstly, the `enumerate` function allows you to iterate with both the index of the item in the list along with the item itself.
For example,

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(index, item)
```

will output

```py
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

compared to

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

which will output

```py
a
b
c
```

If we do

```py
for i in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i)
```

We get

```py
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
```

Meaning you're assigning a bundle (a "tuple") of two values (both the index and the item) to `i`. So that `if` check of yours will never be true as you are trying to check whether a bundle of values equals a single value (which it never will). This is why your function is returning `None`, it never actually gets past the `if` and as such, never returns anything.
This is **issue #1**, you should just be using

```py
for i in x:
    if i == 1:
        ...
```

so you can `if` check only the item.

Now if that `if` check does succeed and Python moved on to the next line, Python would throw an error as the `sum` method requires a list of values to be passed to it rather than a single value (the item).
This is **issue #2**, the summing should wait until you have a full list of values.

Now the final issue - the `return` keyword returns a value from the function and exits it *immediately*, so if the `sum` error was avoided, you would still be leaving the function before you finished iterating the list. This is **issue #3**. You should rather just `append` to the list and `return` the `sum` of it after the iteration is complete.

I think this is more what you were going for:

```py
result=[]

def count(x):
    ones = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == 1:
            result.append(i)
    return sum(result)
```

Or perhaps without the list:

```py
def count(x):
    ones = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == 1:
            ones = ones + 1
    return ones
```

And for fun a recursive solution:

```py
def count(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    i = x.pop()
    if i == 1:
        return 1 + count(x)
    return count(x)
```